# UICollectionView not updating

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to implement parallax effect in my one of the listing page. So I use collectionview and its working fine what I except. But the problem is after I fetch data from my server and reload collectionview, it not working. I have array of object from server also. While debugging I found the issues in

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         print("array count:\ (array_AlbumTracks.count)") // it returns 12 from api server .working fine
        return array_AlbumTracks.count // here if i set return 12...its working fine, but array_AlbumTracks.count not updating the cellForItemAt delegate method
    }
```

I don't know why the

```
collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

is not called. Anyone help me

Finally I found the solution, while reloading array I update UIColectionViewFlowLayout also, check the below code;

```
func apiActionForGetMyList { // inside this function fetch array data from server and while reloading the collectionview 
  DispatchQueque.main.async{
     self.collectionView_Album.reloadData()
     self.collectionView_Album.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout() 
  }
```

}

Comment: Did you call reload data after yo0u get your result from your api call? Sounds like your data source is empty while loading the collection view.

Comment: Yes I called in main thread and normal, but no use

Comment: When I statically set return 12 in 'numberOfItemsInSection' , its working fine and fetch first 12 array object and listing perfectly

Comment: Could `array_AlbumTracks` be empty at some point (so `count` returns zero). I don’t think `cellForItem` will be called if the collection view expects zero rows.

Comment: @Chris , So I need to check the array count right?

Comment: @Prasanth Yes. Use a print statement to check it at any point it might change. Another thing; if your API call returns data asynchronously, you would have to reload the collection view in the completion block closure.

Comment: I use print statement array count is 12. I reload the collectionview in Main thread, once array count is greater than zero.

Comment: Sorry @Chris not working

Comment: @Prasanth Are you saying that this line `print("array count:\ (array_AlbumTracks.count)")` works just right but not this `return array_AlbumTracks.count`??

Comment: yes you are correct, also I checked if the array count is empty in somewhere but no, it have data @iOSer

Comment: Thats weird!! Never heard anything like this.. Try rebooting system, Xcode and device everything

Comment: @iOSer I also facing first time like this...

Comment: @Prasanth Likewise, I’m not sure where the problem is! :)

Comment: @Chris its working check the updated code

Comment: Do not answer your question in the question. Answer it as an answer! Yes answering your own question is perfectly correct on Stack Overflow when you solve it yourself without other people’s answers.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found the solution, while reloading array I update UIColectionViewFlowLayout also, check the below code;

```
func apiActionForGetMyList { 
     DispatchQueque.main.async{
        self.collectionView_Album.reloadData()
        self.collectionView_Album.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout() 
     }
}
```